# How can we plot histogram graph with Apache Echart.js with Single bar highlighted with custom tooltips?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, histogram, echarts

I look on the internet for some example of histogram with echart.js but only find this [one](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-histogram).
I want build somewhat similar to this one with single bar highlighted with custom tooltip.[image]

thanks in adavance for your help and time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide the code you are using? You can change the tooltip option inside series, and customize it as you want it. Use the echarts documentation that gives you a lot of options to make a tooltip [echarts documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.tooltip).
The code would look like these:

```
options:{
tooltip:{},
series: [{
    id: 'taskData',
    type : 'scatter',
    // ...
    tooltip: {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}]
```

}

Comment: would the same will can be done for bar graph

Comment: Yes you can use any type

Comment: thanks for the solution. i found it in docs . i will need to use formatter [link](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.tooltip.formatter)